# Storing The field names in an array in excel-vba

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet-function

I have 10 columns in a worksheet with every worksheet having a specified ID defined in the namebox. How can I store the ID's in an Array using VBA.

p.s. I do not want to store the column headings. I want to store their ID's Which are defined in the namebox for every column.

Comment: What do you mean namebox? Could you post a screenshot and provide more details?

Comment: @Will - I'm taking this to be *named ranges* with the *name box* to the left of the formula bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop through the workbook's named ranges; check that each name refers to a range on that worksheet and that the named range refers to a range that is at least partially in the first row.

```
Dim n As Long, vColNames As Variant
Dim c As Long, twb As Workbook

Set twb = ThisWorkbook

With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
        'dim the array one-based to parallel the columns
        ReDim vColNames(1 To .Columns.Count)

        'loop through all names looking for ones that intersect first row
        For n = 1 To twb.Names.Count
            'check the parent worksheet first
            If twb.Names(n).RefersToRange.Parent.Name = .Parent.Name Then
                ' next check to ensure first row is part of named range
                If Not Intersect(twb.Names(n).RefersToRange, .Rows(1), .Cells) Is Nothing Then
                    vColNames(Intersect(twb.Names(n).RefersToRange, .Rows(1)).Cells(1, 1).Column) = _
                        twb.Names(n).Name
                End If
            End If
        Next n
    End With
End With


For c = LBound(vColNames) To UBound(vColNames)
    Debug.Print vColNames(c)
Next c
```

Names with workbook scope will come out as *myNamedRange*; those with worksheet scope will be in the form of *Sheet1!myNamedRange*.